# what does the letter 'f' do here?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

This is the piece of code here.
It deals with the data analysis of the avocado prices dataset avaialble on kaggle using pandas.

```
graph_df = pd.DataFrame
for r in regions:
  r_df = df.copy()[df['region']==r]
  r_df.set_index("Date", inplace=True)
  r_df.sort_index(inplace=True)
  r_df[f"{r}_25MA"] = r_df['AveragePrice'].rolling(25).mean()

  if graph_df.empty:
    graph_df = r_df[[f"{r}_25MA"]]
  else:
    graph_df = graph_df.join(r_df[f"{r}_25MA"])

graph_df.tail()
```

what i want to know is what does the letter **'f'** before **{r}_25MA** do in this

`r_df[f"{r}_25MA"] = r_df['AveragePrice'].rolling(25).mean()`

```
  if graph_df.empty:
    graph_df = r_df[[f"{r}_25MA"]]
  else:
    graph_df = graph_df.join(r_df[f"{r}_25MA"])
```

if anybody knows please do help and sorry for asking a noob question.

Comment: It's [string interpolation](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#whatsnew36-pep498) also called `f-string`s.

Answer (score 0):

f-strings are a great new way to format strings. For example:

```
text = "is text"
print(f"This {text}")
```

Comment: Hey thanks. i actually used .format and didn't knew about this thanks for the answer :)